# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this2.emailRef.current.focus - How to autofocus an input field when the screen is opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, input, focus

```
class Signin
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
this.emailRef = React.createRef();
    this.passwordRef = React.createRef();
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  }
focusTextInput=()=>{
 this.passwordRef.current.focus()
  }

  componentDidMount=()=> {
    // this.refs.emailRef.focus()
    this.emailRef.current.focus();
    // this.focusTextInput();
  }
render(){
return (
<SafeAreaView>
<Input
                ref={this.emailRef}
/>
</SafeAreaView>
);
}
```

This is resulting in an error like " TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this2.emailRef.current.focus')"

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure "this.emailRef.current" exists before calling focus(), since sometimes it takes time to create the reference.
Try adding a delay as a workaround, for example:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.emailRef.current) {
      this.emailRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, 500);
}
```